# Fortran - Working around go-to's when converting to C

Tags: fortran

Im translating this Fortran code to C code. What is a good way to get around using the go to statements. Ive managed to work around some of the go to statments, but the ones you see below are big 100+ line leaps. I dont know how to tackle this, is there is a easy stratagey to do this without go tos in c?

```
270    IF (R .EQ. 0) THEN
           GO TO 290
       ELSE 
           GO TO 300
       END IF
290    M=M+1; GO TO 400       
300    DO 305 I = 1,L
           IF (ICHAR(D(I)) - ICHAR("-")) 305,320,305
305    CONTINUE
       GO TO 390
```

Comment: One technique is to try to turn the destination of the goto into a function and replace the goto with a function call.  It is hard to say if that will work in your case based on such a small sample.

Comment: Which `GOTO` in your code you have in mind? Where are the destination labels of your `GOTO`s?

Comment: Sorry, i added the rest of the code from the point above here http://pastebin.com/JT0fy3DJ

Comment: If by any chance you have access to "Modern Fortran" by Clerman and Spector, then there's a section on Updating Old Programs, which explains quite well how to convert from F77 to modern Fortran. It might also be useful when converting to C.

Answer (score 1):

Having done a fair amount of restructuring Fortran code to minimize use of `GOTO`, I can tell you that you can often -- usually, even -- map `GOTO`s onto parts of structured programming constructs such as conditional statements, loops, and switches (`SELECT CASE` in Fortran).  In some cases you can safely move around blocks of code to facilitate that.

It's not so uncommon in code with a long history to find that most labels have only one incoming branch, and those cases are typically easy to handle. In such code or otherwise, however, you do have to be careful about lines with multiple incoming branches.

Sometimes it helps to take a step back and analyze the overall subprogram as a unit.  You can get lost among all the individual gotos and labels, but a higher-level analysis may reveal transformation options that are otherwise difficult to discern.  Also, you may need to perform your overall transformation in multiple steps.  By all means, start with the easier bits.  Sometimes clearing those up makes other transformations easier to see or to perform.

I have typically performed such transformations on Fortran code, which would then be straightforward to convert to goto-less C.  If you are more comfortable with C, however, then you could consider a direct translation of your Fortran code to goto-laden C, followed by transforming the C code.  Any way around, however, there is no simple, universal way to solve the problem.

As to your example code, there isn't enough information to judge how to transform it (not even in your longer pastebin snippet).  There may be branches incoming to any of the labeled statements from anywhere else in the subprogram, and you cannot know what transformations are safe without knowing about those.

Comment: I completely agree with this statements, but every now and then you come up with such spaghetti code that you just can't fit it all in your brain. I am wondering if there is tool that parses a single `FORTRAN` procedure and creates either a flow chart or some other way to help refacor such code.

Comment: @ja72, you may find [ftnchek](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftnchek/) of some use.  Although it's billed as a code *checker*, it can perform some transformations that might help you, too.  It won't get you all the way there, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by making the code compile and run correctly in C with some goto statements. Debug that first. That's the important part and may keep you busy for a while. Eliminating all the GOTOs is less important.

Then improve the code incrementally, making it compile and run properly after each refactoring step, whether it removes a goto or does something else.

Note that there's a possibility of introducing bugs while doing this. You can reduce problems by making the code to work first and checking it in to source code control before doing the refactoring steps.

In this example, one such refactoring step would replace the `GO TO 290` statement by copying/moving inline the code it used to jump to: `M=M+1; GO TO 400`. Once you do that, the `ELSE` is easy to simplify.

Similarly, you can replace

```
IF (ICHAR(D(I)) - ICHAR("-")) 305,320,305
```

with

```
if (ICHAR(D(I)) == ICHAR("-")) goto 320
```

and then more code can simplify. (Well, you'll have to do this change before the code will compile in C.)

If the original code is reasonable, most of the GOTOs will turn into reasonable, structured code. If not, you've got spaghetti code on your hands and a bigger problem. In that case, try to make it work, then rewrite it incrementally.

Comment: I'd do the reverse, rework the fortran to cleans it of evil `goto`s, then convert.

Comment: That's a good choice *if* you have a suitable Fortran compiler.

Comment: good point. I suppose your proficiency in `C` would impact the approach decision as well.

Comment: Yes. Also if the plan is to continue evolving this code, then it's important to improve its structure. If the plan is to convert it then run it without changing it, then the GOTOs don't matter. If the plan is to convert it then redesign or rewrite it incrementally, then some parts are worth cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend giving TOOLPACK a spin for refactoring the code.

A version which will require only a little tweaking for a modern unix system (and on the C side, which tells you something about which language is more stable...) can be found at http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/devel/lang/fortran/!INDEX.short.html .

I changed your example a litte (to make it compile) to

```
      SUBROUTINE FOO(D,L)
      CHARACTER*1 D(L)
      INTEGER L
      R = 42.3
      M = 52
 270  IF (R .EQ. 0) THEN
         GO TO 290
      ELSE 
         GO TO 300
      END IF
 290  M=M+1
      GO TO 400       
 300  DO 305 I = 1,L
         IF (ICHAR(D(I)) - ICHAR('-')) 305,320,305
 305  CONTINUE
      GO TO 390

 400  PRINT *,L,M
 390  PRINT *,R
 320  PRINT *,'FOUND'
      END
```

and ran it through TOOLPACK's stf script.  This is what it came up with:

```
      SUBROUTINE FOO(D,L)
      CHARACTER*1 D(L)
      INTEGER L

      R = 42.3
      M = 52
      IF (R.EQ.0) THEN
          M = M + 1

          PRINT *,L,M

      ELSE
          DO 10 I = 1,L
              IF (ICHAR(D(I))-ICHAR('-').EQ.0) GOTO 20
   10     CONTINUE
      ENDIF

      PRINT *,R
   20 PRINT *,'FOUND'
      END
```

It can also do your variable declarations for you etc.

TOOLPACK is **very** strict about adhering to the Fortran 77 standard, so double quotes for strings, `ENDDO` and `IMPLICIT NONE` will not work. IMHO, its capability of transorming spaghetti code into something more structured more than makes up for it.  Also, this is not a program that you will want to run repeatedly on a single source code - you transform your source once (maybe with a few utilities, one after the other) and then continue working on it.

Comment: If you upload a self-contained example (something that compiles on its own), I could run it through TOOLPACK for your.